# Using Magento Embedded ERP, how do I configure the Magento Client Computer on the server

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, erp

I'm using Magento 1.4.1.1, and Maison du Logiciel's extension Embedded ERP 2.7.5.6.

Apparently I need a MagentoClientComputer.xml file but it's *not* included in the EE-2.7.5.6.zip package at all! I looked it over more than once and I looked at the installed files of the Magento Client Computer program and can't find it at all.

What am I supposed to do? What do I need to be able to configure the Client Computer settings on the server?

Comment: That's a pretty esoteric question that someone here **might** be able to answer, although it's borderline. If you paid €600.00 for the  extension I'd suggest seeking out support from your vendor.  http://www.maisondulogiciel.com/

Comment: Already asked there, and someone else did too, but no good answer. I thought I'd toss it out here just in case :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maison Du Logiciel split the Client Computer program into a separate package that must be downloaded separately from their forums.

Answer (score -1):

you probably didn't ask Maisondulogiciel because they would have told you to download it on maisondulogiciel support forum using your credentials

Comment: ...thanks for the insult, I did ask. I got an answer from them, it pointed me to a completely different forum than the one I expected it to be on...